# Print common item from list, and the set()

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here i have some code for Print common item from list,  and the set().
i am not getting what result variable saying.

```
import random
a = random.sample(range(1,30), 12)
b = random.sample(range(1,30), 16)
result = [i for i in set(a) if i in b]
```

what is the meaning of the following line. please explain i new to programming.

```
[i for i in set(a) if i in b]
```

Comment: It prints the common items. I dont see an issue

Answer (score 0):

The last line performs an intersection between values of `a` and `b` in a list comprehension. Only pooly executed:

First I don't see why turning `a` into a `set`. Sampling a `range` of integers always provides distinct values. In that case it doesn't speed processing up, it just messes with the order (which is already random...).

Then, `if i in b` is inefficient (not noticeable if there are only a few values) because of the linear search (`b` being a `list`)

I'd rewrite it like this:

```
a = random.sample(range(1,30), 12)
b = set(random.sample(range(1,30), 16))
result = [i for i in a if i in b]
```

or even better using `set` `intersection` method.

```
result = set(random.sample(range(1,30), 12)).intersection(random.sample(range(1,30), 16))
```

In both rewrites, we create one `set`, to be able to use fast lookup / intersection with the other iterable.

Answer (score 0):

It is called list comprehension, which basically doing a regular loop inside of your array, or dictionary.

A much readable code for beginner python programmer would be:

```
results = []
for i in set(a):
    if i in b:
        results.append(i)
```

You are looking onto the `list(a)` and keeping only those who are in both `list(a)` and `list(b)`.

Comment: much readable? it's just another way to write it. list comprehension _is_ readable.

Comment: readable for beginner, not for someone familiar with the python syntax

Comment: list comprehension are much faster than classical loop constructs. Better educate people to them.